# How can I reveal a hidden window?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I want make a hidden window visible.

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "MyWindowName");
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

The window is found, but nothing happens. It remains hidden.
What am I doing wrong?

If it matters, the application is made using MFC and it has the following method overwritten:

```
void CMyClass::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos) 
{
    lpwndpos->flags &= ~SWP_SHOWWINDOW;

    CDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);
}
```

Comment: If the active window belongs to some process, then Windows does not allow other processes to change the active Window. Maybe this is what you're encountering?

Comment: Fairly obviously, that `OnWindowPosChanging` handler is stopping the window from being shown.

Comment: There's a software called nView from NVIDIA that somehow manages to make it visible. So I know that it is possible. I just don't know how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it.

Apparently you need to modify some flags.

```
long style= GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style |= WS_VISIBLE;
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);

SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

And it works.